# How to split a SQL string into two variables based on delimiter?

Tags: mysql, sql, string, stored-procedures

So I have a function that returns a concatenated string type as such:

```
SELECT @RETURN = @DESTINATION_CELL_VALUE_OUTPUT + '||' + cast(@database_update_output as varchar);

RETURN @RETURN
```

What I want to do is to split @Return into two separate variables, the separator between the two being the '||'

What would be the most efficient way to split this inside a stored procedure?

Comment: A function only returns one value.  What would the function return?

Comment: It is indicated above. The function returns @RETURN.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `substring_index()` to split the string in two, using `||` as a separator:

```
select substring_index(@return, , '||', 1) return1, substring_index(@eturn, '||', -1) return2
```